# Spring R2DBC DatabaseClient losing TZ information

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I have a db entity with some Instant type fields.
org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient (which is now deprecated), had a method `.as(..)` to automatically map to a java entity and it honoured the timezones too. Not sure how that happened internally.

But using org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient which does not have an automatic mapper, I must use a `.map(...)` which provides the Rows and I map them like

`row.get("blah", Instant.class)`
But it just gives time in my local TZ, not UTC.

Anyone knows the root cause? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**

I'm assuming that you are using the PostgresSQL database and appropriate driver. Also, I assume that you are using the `TIMESTAMP` DB type for your `Instant` filed. To get the correct timezone from `org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient` you can use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as a data type.

**Long Answer**

I have created a test repo to test the behavior of `R2dbcRepository` and R2DBC `DatabaseClient` to retrieve `timestamp` and `timestampz` into `Instant`. To do so, I have created the following table:
`CREATE TABLE test_table (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, timestamp_without_tz TIMESTAMP, timestamp_with_tz TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);`

And implemented the following service:

```
package com.patotski.r2dbctimestamps.service;


import com.patotski.r2dbctimestamps.domain.TestEntity;
import com.patotski.r2dbctimestamps.repo.TestEntityRepo;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.time.Instant;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestEntityService {

    private final TestEntityRepo testEntityRepo; // uses standard R2dbcRepository implementation
    private final DatabaseClient databaseClient;

    public Mono<TestEntity> saveUsingRepo(TestEntity entity) {
        return testEntityRepo.save(entity);
    }

    public Mono<TestEntity> getByIdFromRepo(int id) {
        return testEntityRepo.findById(id);
    }

    public Mono<TestEntity> saveUsingDbClient(TestEntity entity) {
        return databaseClient.sql("INSERT INTO test_table (timestamp_without_tz, timestamp_with_tz) VALUES(:timestamp_without_tz, :timestamp_with_tz)")
                .bind("timestamp_without_tz", entity.getTimestamp_without_tz())
                .bind("timestamp_with_tz", entity.getTimestamp_with_tz())
                .map(row -> TestEntity.builder()
                        .id(row.get("id", Integer.class))
                        .timestamp_with_tz(row.get("timestamp_with_tz", Instant.class))
                        .timestamp_without_tz(row.get("timestamp_without_tz", Instant.class))
                        .build()).first();
    }

    public Mono<TestEntity> getByIdFromDbClient(int id) {
        return databaseClient.sql("SELECT * from test_table where id = :id")
                .bind("id", id)
                .map(row -> TestEntity.builder()
                        .id(row.get("id", Integer.class))
                        .timestamp_with_tz(row.get("timestamp_with_tz", Instant.class))
                        .timestamp_without_tz(row.get("timestamp_without_tz", Instant.class))
                        .build()).first();
    }

}
```

And created tests that just store entity and retrieve asserting Timestamps:

```
@SpringBootTest
class TestEntityServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityService testEntityService;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should store and retrieve Entity with both timestamp fields in correct timezones using R2DBC repo.")
    void shouldStoreCorrectTimestampsAndRetriveWithRepo() {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        TestEntity entity = TestEntity.builder()
                .timestamp_with_tz(now)
                .timestamp_without_tz(now)
                .build();

        TestEntity saved = testEntityService.saveUsingRepo(entity).block();

        Assertions.assertThat(testEntityService.getByIdFromRepo(saved.getId()).block()).isNotNull()
                .extracting(TestEntity::getId,
                        TestEntity::getTimestamp_without_tz,
                        TestEntity::getTimestamp_with_tz)
                .containsExactly(saved.getId(), now, now);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should store and retrieve Entity with both timestamp fields in correct timezones using R2DBC DatabaseClient.")
    void shouldStoreCorrectTimestampsAndRetriveWithDbClient() {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        TestEntity entity = TestEntity.builder()
                .timestamp_with_tz(now)
                .timestamp_without_tz(now)
                .build();

        testEntityService.saveUsingDbClient(entity).block();

        Assertions.assertThat(testEntityService.getByIdFromDbClient(1).block()).isNotNull()
                .extracting(TestEntity::getId,
                        TestEntity::getTimestamp_without_tz,
                        TestEntity::getTimestamp_with_tz)
                .containsExactly(1, now, now);
    }
}
```

Results show that these 2 methods are not consistent with each other:

- `R2dbcRepository` test always passes in all TZs
- `DatabaseClient` test passes only when tests are running in UTC TZ and fails when not. The reason is that field defined as `TIMESTAMP` in DB gets TZ offset.
- `TIMESTAMPZ` field works correctly in both cases always

Repo to reproduce: https://github.com/xp-vit/r2dbc-timestamps

Created and issue for Spring team to at least discuss: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/608